# How to map many to many relationship in symfony2 form?

Tags: php, symfony

I have created the blog bundle in that i create the following entity.

```
1.post
2.postcategoryinfo
3.posttaginfo
4.category
5.tag
```

In post form there is category and tag multi selection drop down in form no field in post entity.

Once the post created the multiple category and multiple tag select in same post. And that entry done in **postcategoryinfo table** for category mapping like:

```
IN POST 1 I SELECT 2 CATEGORY

IN post TABLE ID 1 INSERTED
id    name
1     Post1  

IN postcategoryinfo TABLE 
post_id   category_id
1            1
1            2

same way in posttaginfo tabel 
post_id   tag_id
1            1
1            2
```

How can i make relation between this three table in post form.

At the time of edit how can i make this category and tag selected in drop down.

Comment: The whole point of a many to many is that you could have multiple categories and tags per post. A dropdown, in contrast, allows you to select only one.

Answer (score 2):

In your Post Entity following field need to add:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Com\YourBundle\Entity\Category", inversedBy="postcatagory")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="postcategoryinfo",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="post_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Com\YourBundle\Entity\Tag", inversedBy="posttag")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="posttaginfo",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="post_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    private $tag;
```

In your category entity:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Com\YourBundle\Entity\Post", mappedBy="category")
     */
    private $postcategory;
```

In your tag entity:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Com\YourBundle\Entity\Post", mappedBy="tag")
     */
    private $posttag;
```

In your postType:

```
     ->add('category', NULL, array(
            'label' => 'Category',
            'class' => 'YourBundle:Category',
            'property' => 'category_name', // Whatever your field name
       }))
     ->add('tag', NULL, array(
            'label' => 'Tag',
            'class' => 'YourBundle:Tag',
            'property' => 'tag_name', // Whatever your field name
       }))
```

Now you can render your Post form in twig in your way. It will do it's work in create and edit with multi select combo.